# What type of basil is this?

Tags: identification, basil

[image]

We can't remember what type of basil this is. We've been growing it in an aquaponic setup. The leaves have started to grow really large and they are quite a deep green colour. It's got quite a fragrant smell. It's not purple at all (only slightly so on the larger, thicker stems) and we've never let it flower (we always harvest it).

It's not hairy on the stem or leaves. It grows with a grow light and directly in water (from cuttings) and we're not sure if that changes the flatness of the leaves.

Comment: Are you sure it's a basil? It looks more like a mint to me.

Comment: Good question, are you 100% sure its basil, doesn't look like any Basil I've ever seen before - doesn't look like mint either though!

Comment: The two varieties with large leaves that I'm aware of are "lettuce leaf" and 'mostruoso" - but that looks quite different and somewhat not-basil-like, though if it smells/tastes right it must be some sort...

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't have that puffiness around the veins that most basil do. More like Thai basil but the leaves don't match. Kind of looks like Magical Michael. Does it develop purple flowers? Here's a list of different types of basil, maybe searching for photos of the different varieties might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_basil_cultivars

Comment: Hahaha yes it is definitely basil!! I have eaten it and can confirm its basilyness. We make pesto with it. We bought it as basil but can't remember what it was labelled as. I actually thought it was labelled as genovese but it's definitely not that.

Comment: It has never flowered so we don't know about the flower colours, sorry!

Comment: Where did you buy it? Maybe it's mutant Genovese basil. You might try to spread it around! ;) Can you take another picture, farther away? It looks like some of those leaves are about the size of your hand.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is Blue African Basil, Ocimum kilimandscharicum x basilicum.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_blue_basil

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like [Ocimum gratissimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocimum_gratissimum). Also known as 'Rama Tulsi' in India.

See images here - [Rama Tulsi](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rama%20tulsi&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN808IN808&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbl87fj-3eAhVVT30KHR8TAYEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=LOBOQfGPL5i9tM:)

Its a kind of basil.